# Passing data from python chunk to R environment in Rnotebook

Tags: python, r, rstudio, rnotebook

I've got some data given to me in a python shelve file, I want to pass it to R for plotting. my code to extract it looks like this:

Try executing this chunk by clicking the *Run* button within the chunk or by placing your cursor inside it and pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*.

````
```{python}
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma, array
import shelve

MODEL = "May2016"
d = shelve.open('fits_shelve_' + MODEL)
hilldata = d['hilldata']
allchi  = d['allchi']
aa      = d['aa'] 
rr      = d['rr'] 
names   = d['names']
weight  = d['weight']
weightc = d['weightc']
dl      = d['dl']
vi      = d['activatorM']
activatorM = d['activatorM']
activatorR = d['activatorR']
d.close()

```
````

I would now like to pass these object to R. Is there a way to do this in Rnotebook? I know something similar is possible with SQL chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for python/R interaction you'll have to save the data to the file system in one chunk and read it back in another.

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_knitr_engines.html#python

Comment: at least for now. I believe this will be addressed in a future release of Rstudio

Answer (score 0):

### 2023 Update

You can pass variables to and from python and R chunks using the R interface object (called `r`). When you use python within R, an R interface object is created that stores environment variables from R, but the cool thing is that you can also add to it from python too. In this example below, I transfer a variable from python to R and then from R to python.

````
```{python}
my_py_var = "This variable came from python"
r.my_py_var = my_py_var
```

```{r}
print(my_py_var)
my_r_var = "This variable came from R"
```

```{python}
print(r.my_r_var)
```
````

I am using R version 4.3.1, python version 3.9.18, reticulate version 1.32.0, and Rstudio version "Desert Sunflower" Release (b51c81cc, 2023-09-25) for CentOS 7.